# Изменения внешнего вида slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

нужно сделать вот такую внешний вид у slick slider
надо сделать так чтобы видна была кусок предыдущего слайда и кусок следующего (что бы было понятно что можно листать слайдер )
Спасибо!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так а в чем проблема? там в примере есть Center Mode.

Comment: посмотрите "Swiper Slider" у него очень обширное api

Comment: Andrey Ivasko может напишите код (а то я сам не смог реализовать )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуй, Антон! Это пример для понимания опции **centerMode**. Всё более подробно описано в документации slick carousel на их же сайте.

```js
$("#items-slide").slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: "60px"
});
```

```css
#items-slide {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.slide {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  background-color: #0950c1;
  border: 4px solid #666;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 26px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(even) .slide {
  background-color: #5b9aff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="items-slide">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
  <div class="slide">4</div>
</div>
```

*P.S stackoverflow - место где задают вопросы, и отвечики объясняют что да как. По этому я попрошу в следующий раз не просить сделать ту или иную вещь вместо вас, а просить помочь с объяснением проблемы и как его можно и/или нужно решить. Это просто, на будущее.*

Comment: Спасибо, за пример и объяснения. сделал так: добавил centerMode и бордер у под блока  слайдера  все проблема решена 
js --> $("#items-slide").slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: "30px"
});
css
#items-slide .slide {
  border: 8px solid #fffbdb;
}

Comment: Рад был помочь. Обращайтесь!